# Execute a Perl script after reboot on Solaris 10

Tags: unix, bash, perl, solaris-10

During my activities on Solaris 10 machine I need twice reboot the Solaris unit and after reboot I'd like to run several scripts.

Before first reboot I store in `/etc/rc3.d/S99myScript` some bash script.The script runs OK after reboot

Before second reboot I store in the same place under same name `/etc/rc3.d/S99myScript` Perl script. After reboot the script does not run.

When I execute Perl script manually on my Solaris machine the script working OK.

What is going on here?

Comment: Why do you switch the scripts? What's wrong with one conditional rc.script running your 1st reboot script if (insert logic here: eg. last reboot done by your perl script or last reboot > 10 mins ago) and your pl script else? You could even use a another file containing the script to load next. Did I miss something? BTW, what does the log say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solaris 10 and older rc scripts are strictly old bourne shell syntax. The sheband I suspect you added is ignored. If you need to run a perl script, just call it with `perl myscript.perl` from your rc script instead.

By the way, rc scripts are still supported but deprecated by SMF on Solaris 10 and newer.